# What is the meaning of "from" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "from the boots up" and "from the mane down" in the following sentences(Source: Cowgirl Kate and Cocoa Written by Erica Silverman ),

> " 'Are you a real cowgirl?' he asked. 'I am a cowgirl **from the boots
>   up**,' she said. 'Well, I am a cowhorse **from the mane down**,' he
>   said. 'Will you work hard every day?' the cowgirl asked. The horse
>   raised his head high. 'Of course,' he said, 'a cowhorse always does
>   his job.' 'At last,' said the cowgirl, 'I have found my horse.' "

Does it mean "I am a cowgirl with the boots up" and "I am a cowhorse with the mane down"?

Does "from" in the sentences mean "with" ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From** is about the *starting point* of the *range* here:

> I'm a cowgirl [*in every part of me*, starting] **from** the boots and **up**
>   [**to** my hat/head].

The horse answers in 'reversed' manner by mentioning its *highest* body part first (starting **from** the mane), thus the 'direction' is **down** (**to** my lowest part).

Comment: Another example: I fell off my bicycle and bruised my arm from the elbow to the wrist.